# Using subscription-key and OAuth2 flow in the same API at the same time

Tags: api, security, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, api-key

I want to use subscription-key + OAuth2 for the same API
OAuth2 for the security robustness
And Subscription-Key for adding another layer of security and using it as an identifier of the company(so it can be rotated), avoiding handing out the IDs.

I am trying to find any literature that supports my approach of using both layers of security for reference purposes, but all I can find is a comparison between them.

Does anyone have a thought on that or a material that could support it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding a security key and tokens will give you that much more security.

An alternative that many might consider is to add transport level security instead, securing HTTPS in different ways, perhaps including adding client side certificates.